# IFrames And The Back Button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Consider the following HTML: (Written for Google Chrome)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      function AddToIFrame(){
        var Frame=document.getElementById("BackTest").contentWindow.document;
        Frame.open();
        Frame.write(Math.random());
        Frame.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="BackTest" name="BackTest" width="100%" height="222"></iframe>
    <a href="javascript:AddToIFrame();">Add To IFrame</a>
    <p>How Can I Modify This HTML So That After Clicking The Link Above, I Can Use The Back Button To Go To Previous IFrame Content?</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Each time you click the link, the content of the iframe will change.  This works great - and for my purposes, MUST use document.write to change the iframe content.

My problem is that I want the back button to cycle back though the previous contents of the iframe - like it does on many other pages.  What happens in this example though is that the back button will take me to the previous main page.

How can I make it so that the back button will cause the iframe to revert, until the iframe is out of history, and only THEN go "back" from the main page?

Comment: Why "MUST use document.write"??

Comment: Because there is no URL that represents the HTML I want to render - I generate the HTML dynamically, on the fly, from JavaScript

Comment: There's plenty of DOM manipulation techniques which are much better than raw `document.write`.  Among other things, they'll allow you to copy and save and move and remove nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy-peasy with some new HTML5 features.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var inner;
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        inner = document.getElementById('inner').contentWindow;
        inner.document.open();
        inner.document.write(
          "\x3cscript\x3e" +
            "var contents = document.getElementById('contents');" +
            "window.addEventListener('load', function() {" +
              "contents = document.getElementById('contents');" +
            "}, false);" +
            "window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {" +
              "history.pushState(e.data, '', '');" +
              "contents.value = e.data;" +
            "}, false);" +
            "window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {" +
              "contents.value = e.state;" +
            "}, false);" +
          "\x3c/script\x3e" +
          '\x3ctextarea id="contents" readonly\x3e\x3c/textarea\x3e'
        );
        inner.document.close();
      }, false);
      function messageInner() {
        inner.postMessage(Math.random(), '*');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="inner"></iframe>
    <a href="#" onclick="messageInner(); return false">Clickety</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `document.write` really should't be used, though; just host your own page (with `<iframe src="…">`) with that inner script.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Frame.open();` use `Frame.open('text/html', 'replace');`.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's not the answer you're looking for, but i don't think that this is at all possible, as the back button is controlled by the browser and not by javascript.

You could modify your code to when a user clicks the button you could do

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.youradress.com/yourpage?iframeurl=' + iframeurl;
```

and on pageload you load the iframe with the url in the querystring

this way, you get a full page load, and the url stays in the history and the back button works as you want